# Sum of decimal digits of primes as a power of a number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I could not find the answer to this question:

Find greatest prime such that:

$p<10^n$

$S_d=k^m$; $m≥ 2$

Where $S_d$ is the sum of digits of $p$, k and m are integers.

For example the greatest prime $p<10^4$ it's sum of digits is a power of an integer is $9907$ such that $9+9+0+7=25=5^2$.

We can find small primes such as $9907$ by reasoning. For large primes we may use computer. But which of the following algorithms can be faster:

a- For example we find for $p<10^4$:

Clearly $S_d< 4\times 9=36$. Take perfect powers less than $36$ which are $2^5, 3^3, 5^2, 4^2, 2^4, 3^2, 2^2$

$2^4$ and $4^2$ give $9511$ and $5^2$ gives $9907$, so the required prime can be $9907$; for this we can assume $d_1=d_2=9$, then $S_d= 9+9+d_3+d_4$, the numbers for $d_3$ and $d_4$ can be:

$(d_3, d_4)=(6, 1), (0, 7), (4, 3)$ only $d_3=0$ and $d_4=7$ can give proper number $d_1d_2d_3d_4=9907$. Similarly we can find other primes which are smaller than $9907$.

b- Check all primes, sum their digits and see whether they are powers of numbers. We can start from primes close to $10^n$.

It is not known which algorithm can be faster for computer, specially for large primes.

Another question comes out that : Among  primes for certain n for what primes k is greatest?

Finally, is there more efficient algorithm for these questions?

Comment: Well, there are a lot of primes and relatively few perfect powers, so I'd lead with the latter.

Comment: Perhaps you should include in your post the requirement, $m\ge2$.

Comment: Also, the digits of $9839$ do not add up to $3^3$. Indeed, if the digits of $n$ add up to a multiple of three, then $n$ is a multiple of three, and cannot be prime (unless $n=3$).

Comment: Thanks for your correcting comments, I edit my question.

Comment: It depends on how efficient you program, any number with an odd number of odd digits necessarily has the base of the power odd. any prime of form $6k+5$ necessarily has to be an odd exponent, and $3j+2$ base.

Comment: This pari/gp - program finds the primes by brute force. Upto $50$ digits, the results appear very fast. For larger $n$, there will be a slowdown because of the need of checking many primes in some cases, but I doubt anyway that we have anything better : for(s=4,100,n=10^s;p=precprime(n);while(ispower(sumdigits(p))==0,p=precprime(p-1));print(s,"  ",p,"  ",sumdigits(p)))

Comment: Sham on serial down voter on my questions.